# Is there a good name for the class of assumptions encoded in "isochoric," "isobaric," "isothermal" etc.?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology

As stated, I'm simply wondering if there is some way to describe holding, or assuming any single one of those state-variables constant.

Something like `isounicratic` or `captomagtiguous` except someone who knows Latin well-enough to spell this right has already thought of this, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a good name for the class of assumptions encoded in
> "isochoric," "isobaric," "isothermal" etc.?

I'm not sure what you mean by "class of assumptions" but in the case of an ideal gas and reversible process, all these processes fall under the general category of a "polytropic process" where

$$PV^{n}=const$$ where $n$, is the "polytropic index", and

$n=0$ for an isobaric process

n=infinity for an isochoric (constant volume) process

$n=1$ for an  isothermal (constant temperature) process

$n=\gamma = \frac{C_P}{C_V}$ for an adiabatic process

Hope this helps.

Comment: So this narrows it down, it seems the word I'm looking for is simply "monotropic" or "isotropic" alluding to the fact that I'm holding one of the state variables constant. To explain further, I was working through understanding a model of a cooler that assumed, due to the much larger $k$ thermal conductivity that through a phase change that solid-fluid system could be modeled as isothermic. I wanted to generalize that technique across all state variables, so "isotropic assumption" would be how I would call that. Or "along the sheet" in general -- "tropy" -- Thanks!

Comment: @meltyness Note that "isotropic" would more commonly be understood as meaning "uniform in all directions". And in chemistry "monotropic" means that a substance that has only one polymorph that is stable (at reasonable temperatures). That is just to say that you probably want to clearly define your "isotropic assumption", if you end up using that term.